# XML внутри HTML

Tags: html, xml

Можно ли внутри html тега вывести каким то образом XML, то есть чтобы браузер не распозновал это как HTML и пытался его вывести а именно как XML. Очень нужно но не получается,браузер пытается распознать это как HTML и не отображает мне ниодин тег а только данные внутри них

Comment: Попробуйте добавить XML между тегами <pre> </pre>?

Comment: Не получается,браузер комментирует объявление xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно что-то в этом духе? Тогда `innerText` Вам поможет.

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<root>\n  <child1>something</child1>\n  <child2>more something</child2>\n</root>';
var el = document.getElementById('xml').innerText = xml;
```

```html
<pre id='xml'></pre>
```